# Ionic multiple ion-slides with different effects on same page issue

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ion-slides

I have a first ion-slides with effect cube.
Then when I try to add a second ion-slides, the screen is blank. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

My code is per below.

```
<div class="body-content">
    <ion-slides [effect]='type' [pager]='showPager' *ngIf="employees" class="main-emp-slide" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">

      <ion-slide class="ion-slide-main" *ngFor="let employee of employees">
        <table class="employer-details">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="prev-emp"> <button (click)="goToPreviousSlide()"> <ion-icon class="icon-size" name="ios-arrow-back"></ion-icon></button></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="counter-text">{{pager.currentPage}} out of {{pager.totalPages}} employees</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="next-emp"> <button (click)="goToNextSlide()"> <ion-icon class="icon-size" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon></button></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <tr>
            <ion-slides pager>
              <ion-slide>
                <h1>slide 1</h1>
              <ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                <h1>slide 2</h1>
              <ion-slide>
           </ion-slides>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </ion-slide>
       </ion-slides>
</div>
```